# How find angle between two different pitch roof

Tags: math, geometry, computational-geometry, revit-api

I'm trying to find the common line angle between adjacent roof lines having different pitch as shown in below diagram[image]

Please let me know how the angle can be determined .

I tried arctan(8/12)= 33.69 degree and arctan(14/12)=49.3987 degree but couldn't find any solution around it.

Comment: Note that these are not _actual_ angles but, projected angles. What I mean is that it is the angle between the projected crease lines to the horizontal plane.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a programming question .. I would just use Blender or alike

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the angle *ψ* formed between one side and the projection of the crease line

[image: fig1]

<sub>Note that the other angle is just `90° - ψ`.</sub>

The crease line in 3D has a direction vector **`e`** with three components `(e_x,e_y,e_z)` of which the *z*-component is ignored to get

```
tan(ψ) = e_y / e_x
```

But how do we get these direction components?

Look at the problem in 3D, and the crease line is where the two rooflines intersect

[image: fig2]

The first roofline is a rotation about the *x*-axis with pitch `14/12`, or angle

```
φ_x = atan(14/12) = 49.39870°
```

The direction normal to the plane is thus

```
      |  0        |   |  0     |
n_x = | -sin(φ_x) | = | -8/√85 |
      |  cos(φ_x) |   |  6/√85 |
```

Similarly the second roofline is a rotation about the *y*-axis with pitch `8/12`, or angle

```
φ_y = atan(y/12) = 33.6901°
```

The direction normal to the plane is thus

```
      | -sin(φ_y) |   | -2/√13 |
n_y = |  0        | = |  0     |
      |  cos(φ_y) |   |  3/√13 |
```

The crease line direction is found from the vector cross-product

```
                | e_x |   | 21/√1105 |
e = n_y × n_x = | e_y | = | 12/√1105 |
                | e_z |   | 14/√1105 |
```

So the roofline angle is

```
ψ = atan(e_x/e_y) = atan( 21/12 ) = 29.7449°
```

---

There is a shortcut to the above.

```
ψ = atan(p_2/p_1) = atan(8/14) = 29.7449°
```

where `p_1 = 14/12` and `p_2 = 9/12` are the two pitch values.

Answer (score 0):

I like John's answer. For a shorter version: the two roof parts define two planes. Calculate the intersection line between the two planes and determine its angle up from horizontal, i.e., in the plane defined by the Z direction and the intersection line itself. I assume that is the gist of Joh's answer as well. And, I totally agree that this question has nothing whatsoever to do with programming.